# What CMS do you use with your ASP.NET Web App

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system

Generally speaking Web apps need an associated CMS to allow the deployment of help information, marketing information, associated blogs, forums and so forth.

Most CMS's tend to be PHP/python based, and don't mesh well with ASP.NET apps (for example, the forum logons don't mix well with your app logons) and they also don't seem to work well in source code control.

What CMS do you use or recomend to support your ASP.NET web app?

Answer (score 2):

You could checkout BrickPile
http://nuget.org/List/Packages/BrickPile